# PHP Cookies not being loaded when coming from a clicked link

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I'm working on a website that is keeping a user session token in $_SESSION. When I type the URL directly, I can load the cookies just fine, but when I click on a page that loads the cookie through PHP, it can't find the cookie. Is there any way to get around this?

Here's the code for saving the cookie

```
setcookie("tpl_token", $token, time()+365*24*60*60, "/");
```

And for retrieving

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['tpl_token'])){
    $token = $_COOKIE['tpl_token'];
} else {
    echo "Cookie not set";
}
```

It is returning that cookie is not set.

Comment: Please show us your code so we can diagnose your problem.

Comment: Updated, sorry about that.

Comment: Is the `tpl_token` supposed session cookie ?

Comment: Could you not just use `session_start()` ?

Comment: Would that affect the cookie loading?

Comment: I just figured it out. My href was directing to http://example.com as opposed to http://www.example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a session in PHP, use the `session_start()` function. PHP handles sessions internally for you, so you do not have to do any dirty work.

Example:

```
session_name("tpl_token");
session_start(); //sends session cookie with name "tpl_token"

//create session variable.
$_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;

if(isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])){
//stuff to do if user is logged in already
} else {
//stuff to do if user is not logged in.
}

//Destroy Session/Logout;
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

If you are try create session cookies, there is no need for the `$_COOKIE[]` function